# Update plane texture offset from movement on a sphere

Tags: three.js, webgl

I'm working on a driving simulation in Three.js using height map data from the planet Venus.

GitHub repo here: https://github.com/hypothete/venus-walk

[image: A picture of the simulation]

Here's how the simulation works so far:

- In a hidden scene, a camera called the globeCamera moves at a fixed height over a sphere textured with the Venus height map. You can see this happening in the lower left viewport in my picture. The globeCamera renders its view to a WebGLRenderTarget to be used as a local height map. The result is in the second viewport in the middle left.
- In the visible scene, a plane mesh called the terrainMesh has its vertices displaced up and down in correspondence with the values from the local height map. This gives the illusion that a vehicle placed in the center of the plane is moving across a surface when actually we're just updating the plane's vertices from the movement of the globeCamera.
- Since I know the rotation of the globeCamera, I can pass that value to my fragment shader to rotate the terrainMesh's rock texture with the height map.

How can I offset the rock texture's position so that texture units translate with the terrain as well? I've tried tracking the globeCamera's offset as a 2D vector and adding that to the rotated UV in the fragment shader, but my results were inconsistent. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @gman Just for future reference, what disqualifies this as a WebGL question? I'm asking about a behavior in a fragment shader and not architecture specific to Three.js.

Comment: sorry, i missed that part